# How to display records from two tables slectively in the order of when they are created

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

Lets say we have two tables with id and timestamp columns.
How can we display the ids of first 10 records from both the tables selectively in the order of timestamp.

e.g 1st we created a record in table1, then we created a record in table2, then we created a record in table1, then we created a record in table2 ........ so on.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? You tagged this with Oracle, mysql and sql server.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your RDBMS, you can use ROWNUM, LIMIT, or create your own Row_Number with Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY datefield DESC).

This might work (for Oracle).

```
select *
from  
( select id, datefield from Table1 
   union select id, datefield From Table2 order by datefield desc )  t
where ROWNUM <= 10;
```

And for MySQL:

```
select *
from  
( select id, datefield from table 
   union select id, datefield from table2 ) t
order by datefield desc
limit 10;
```

And for SQL Server:

```
select * 
from
(
    select *, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY datefield DESC) as rown
    from  
    ( select id, datefield from table 
       union select id, datefield from table2 ) t
 ) t2
 where rown <= 10
```

Good luck.

Comment: I've updated my answer -- thanks here is the fiddle for oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bc3f/1

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Sgeddes

Comment: No problem -- glad I could help.  BTW -- if any response on the post answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.  That will help future users searching the site.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if is this what you are looking for. This will work in MySql:

```
SELECT 'table1' tab, id, timestamp
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' tab, id, timestamp
FROM table2
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10
```

and will select last 10 records inserted in one of `table1` or `table2`. This will work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (
  SELECT TOP 10 'table1' tab, id, timestamp
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP 10 'table2' tab, id, timestamp
  FROM table2
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC ) t
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```